# Как сделать функцию login_user для сайта на Django

Tags: python, django

Всем доброго времени суток

Я делаю небольшой сайт на Django и мне нужно сделать функцию login_user.

У меня есть шаблон login_form, с которого я хочу считать данные, но нету самой функции login_user

Как мне ее сделать ?

Файл login_form.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% extends 'chat/base.html' %}
    {% block title %}Messenger | Login{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <h3>Login</h3>
                            {% if error_message %}
                                <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
                            {% endif %}
                            <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {%  csrf_token %}
                                {% for field in form %}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                            <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">{{ field }}</div>
                                        </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn-success">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Файл urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартная вьюха для авторизации должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
def login_user(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        #Ваша логика для авторизованных пользователей
```